# Limit output to one block

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page listing all articles. Each article has video blocks, and I add this video to the button for a specific article

```
<div class="blog-list">
@foreach($articles as $article)
  <div class="blog-article">

    @foreach($article->articleBlocks as $article_block)
    @if($article_block->type === \App\Models\ArticleBlock::TEXT_VIDEO)
    <div class="video-button video-modal-button-blog" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $article_block->video_link }}">
      <span>Watch video</span>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach

    <h2 class="blog-article__title">{{ $article->title }}</h2>
    <span>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($article->published_at)) }}</span>
    <span>{{ $article->getTotalViews() }} Views</span>
  </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

This cycle begins

```
@foreach($article->articleBlocks as $article_block)
```

I have 4 types of blocks, and before displaying a block with a video, I need to define it

```
@if($article_block->type === \App\Models\ArticleBlock::TEXT_VIDEO)
```

But the problem is that an article may have several such blocks with video, and then several such buttons are displayed in the code, depending on the number of blocks

I need to limit the output to only one block, preferably the very first

I tried to use `$loop->first`, but it displays the first video for the first article in the list, and the rest is empty

Are there any other options?

Comment: You could add an if-else statement to check if there are multiple entries in your array. If is more than one entry you use '$loop->first', if there is only one entry you use it directly.

Comment: I'm not sure why your `$loop->first` won't work. But you could put a `@break` before your `@endforeach` to exit the loop after it's first run.

Comment: is `articleBlocks` a relationship?

Comment: @lagbox Yes that's right

Comment: you could just ask the collection for the first element `@if ($article_block = $article->articleBlocks->first()) ...` instead of the foreach

Comment: @lagbox it turns out the same as with `$loop->first`, displays the first video for the first article in the list, and the rest is empty

Comment: the rest what is empty? ... this would limit this to 1 block per article

Comment: @lagbox well, I have a list of articles, and without a cycle, this only works for the first article, in the rest of the articles nothing is displayed at all

Comment: based on what you have here that would mean the other articles don't have blocks

Comment: @lagbox maybe, but there are blocks there, and with foreach everything is displayed normally, it just displays several of these blocks with buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add `$loop->first` inside child iteration

Lets say I have sample array

```
$loopArray = [
    [
        'title' => 'Title 1',
        'published_at' => now()->subDays(rand(1,10))->subMinutes(rand(1,100))->format('d F Y'),
        'articleBlocks' => [
            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 1 Vid 1',
                'video_link' => 'Title 1 Link 1',
                'video_type' => 'audio',
            ],
            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 1 Vid 2',
                'video_link' => 'Title 1 Link 2',
                'video_type' => 'video',
            ],
            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 1 Vid 3',
                'video_link' => 'Title 1 Link 3',
                'video_type' => 'video',
            ],
        ]
    ],

    [
        'title' => 'Title 2',
        'published_at' => now()->subDays(rand(1,10))->subMinutes(rand(1,100))->format('d F Y'),
        'articleBlocks' => [
            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 2 Vid 1',
                'video_link' => 'Title 2 Link 1',
                'video_type' => 'video',
            ],
            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 2 Vid 2',
                'video_link' => 'Title 2 Link 2',
                'video_type' => 'audio',
            ],
            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 2 Vid 3',
                'video_link' => 'Title 2 Link 3',
                'video_type' => 'video',
            ],
        ]
    ],

    [
        'title' => 'Title 3',
        'published_at' => now()->subDays(rand(1,10))->subMinutes(rand(1,100))->format('d F Y'),
        'articleBlocks' => [
            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 3 Vid 1',
                'video_link' => 'Title 3 Link 1',
                'video_type' => 'audio',
            ],
            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 3 Vid 2',
                'video_link' => 'Title 3 Link 2',
                'video_type' => 'audio',
            ],

            [
                'vid_name' => 'Title 3 Vid 3',
                'video_link' => 'Title 3 Link 3',
                'video_type' => 'video',
            ],
        ]
    ],
];
```

And the blade file like this

```
 @foreach ($loopArray as $eachLoop)

<li>Title:  {{$eachLoop['title']}}</li>
    @foreach (collect($eachLoop['articleBlocks'])->filter(function($eachArray){
        return $eachArray['video_type'] === 'video';
    }) as $eachBlock)
        @if ($loop->first)
           <ul>Video Id: {{$eachBlock['video_link']}}</ul>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This will produce the result like this you can see live demo [here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/0b3aad59-ce3c-43ab-9719-585c29114339) and
Updated demo [here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/f4930a56-396d-482a-8745-b9e0bd187f19)

[image]

so

```
    @foreach($article->articleBlocks->filter(function($eachArticleBlocks){
return $eachArticleBlocks->type\App\Models\ArticleBlock::TEXT_VIDEO;
}) as $article_block)
      @if($loop->first)
        <div class="video-button video-modal-button-blog" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $article_block->video_link }}">
          <span>Watch video</span>
        </div>
       @endif
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help, there is just one more thing, I forgot to add to the article, I have 4 types of blocks, and before displaying a block with a video, I need to define it, 
updated post

Comment: Even though it works I strongly advise you to use ```hasOne``` relations with where condition